# Wordpress doesn't apply CSS changes

Tags: css, wordpress, caching

I was creating a custom template for a wordpress webbsite and for the first time after I add new classes in the style.css and I apply the changes, the website doesn't save them. I tried many times to delete the cache and change browser but nothing. When I open the style sheet from wordpress ACP I can see the changes but from google chrome with the webmaster tool I see nothing, like it shows the old css version. I am using WP Super Cache also.

Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a query killer at the end of the css file might also override any possible caching mechanisms.

Ie: example.com/style.css should be accessed via example.com/style.css?test